# How to input during an amount of time?

Tags: grammar, time

How do I correctly write someone has been doing this for this certain amount of time? For example:

> Next 30 years he wrote multiple books.

or should I write it:

> He wrote multiple books in 30 years.

*It can be informal*

Comment: Over the next 30 years he wrote multiple books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*During the last 30 years he wrote (or has written) ...*

*For the past 30 years he has written (or has been writing) ...*

*Over the last (or past) 30 years, he wrote (or has written) ..."*

Your choice will depend mostly on whether his writing is on-going or has ended.

Also, "multiple books" is borderline redundant.  If you wish to imply that he was prolific and wrote a lot of books, then say "a lot of books" or "many books".  The term "multiple books" doesn't really carry any additional meaning other than a number of books greater than one.